# How to make a cell mandatory to complete when another cell has changed?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

If cell L6 shows yes or no, a message box appears to confirm cell L7 and L8 must be completed . I saw a similar post, but I couldn't get the VBA coding to work for my situation. Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Could you share the VBA that wasn't working for you and let us know what was wrong with it?

Comment: Is the goal to show a message box, to prevent the user from moving on until the mandatory content has been entered, or to allow the users to do other stuff but not complete the "session" without going back to perform the cell entry?  Is the data entry required to be validated?

Comment: @Dannielle, to avoid VBA, you can use IF then Else in any blank cell through test  L6 for Yes or No, since you need only an Alert message or you may go with Data Validation also!

Comment: @Dannielle, or you can set Data validation for L7 & L8 (is L6 is neither Blank nor any value others than Yes or No !!  Or if you are comfortable with VBA then I can suggest one!!

Answer (score 1):

*To achieve the goal, I would like to suggest two possible methods.*

**Method 1, Data Validation:**

- *Situation 1*, when Cell `L6` is filled with either `Yes` or `No`.

[image]

---

- *Situation 2*, when Cell `L6` is filled with neither `Yes` nor `No`.

[image]

---

- *Situation 3*, when Cell `L6` is `Blank`.

[image]

---

**How it works:**

1. Select cells `L7` & `L8` and from **Data Tab** click **Data Validation.**
2. Set **Custom** as Validation Criteria and enter this Formula.

`=NOT(ISBLANK($L$6))*(OR($L$6="Yes",$L$6="No"))`

3. Finish with **Ok**

---

**Method 2, VBA (Macro):**

- Right Click the **Sheet Tab** & hit **View Code** from the Poped up menu to get VB editor.
- **Copy & Paste** this Code as **Standard Module** with the Sheet.

  ```
  Option Explicit

  Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

  If Not Intersect(Target, Range("L6")) Is Nothing Then

      If Target.Value = "Yes" Or Target.Value = "No" Then
          MsgBox "Now You Can fill L7 & L8"
      Range("L7").Activate

      ElseIf Target.Value <> "Yes" Or Target.Value <> "No" Then
          MsgBox "Target cell must have data Yes Or No,, to fill L7 & L8"
      Target.Activate
      End If

      If Target.Value = "" Then
      MsgBox "Target Cell Can't be Blank,,"
      Target.Activate
      End If
  End If

  End Sub
  ```

**N.B.**

- This code will start responding as soon you fill the Cell `L6`.
- You may adjust cell references in the Formula as well as in VBA code as needed.